# connecting to webservice with kSOAP in android

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

I am trying to connect web service with kSOAP Library. code send 4 fields like username and password, name and family to the server but in server everything received null ! this is my code where is the problem?
WebService.java

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.util.Log;


public class WebService {
    private static String NAMESPACE = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public final static String URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static final String METHOD = "Register";
    public static String invokeWS() {
        String resTxt = null;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

        request.addProperty("username","user");
        request.addProperty("password","pass");
        request.addProperty("name","MyName");
        request.addProperty("family","MyFamily");
        Log.v("", ""+request);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
                         new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER12);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {            
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+METHOD, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resTxt = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {        
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("",""+e);
            resTxt = "Error !!!!";
        } 
        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

and call invokeWS() in MainActivity.java

```
 AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
//Call execute 
task.execute();
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
displayText = WebService.invokeWS();
return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
//Set response
Log.v("", "Recive : "+displayText);
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {  
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
}
}
```

Comment: Try to add this: `envelope.dotNet=true` after initializing envelope object

Comment: Great ! its work fine Thank man.

Comment: Can I post an answer could you accept it with upvote?

Comment: yes man i accept it.

Comment: Done now you can upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add This Line To Your Code:

`envelope.dotNet=true`